# How can I log the output of a session generated by the "screen" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

I am running several Screen sessions in the same directory at the same time.

When the program in a certain session is completed, this session is terminated automatically. However, I need to check the output of the session. So I tried to use "screen -L" to keep a log. However, the outputs of all the sessions were logged into a single file, *screenlog.0* (several lines from one session and then several lines from another session... which is impossible to read).

Is there a method to record different sessions to different log files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[Is it possible to name the 'screen' logfile from the -L flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026184)*

Answer (score 1):

You can, for instance, use the `logfile` command in screenrc.

Comment: Thannks! Could you please give me some details? I am really a newbie to Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure what you do and how and what is your ultimate goal, I can only suggest here that you try `man screen` and look if you wind something that suits your exact needs there.