# Is it possible to name the 'screen' logfile from the -L flag?

Tags: linux, logging, gnu-screen

Upon running [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) with the -L flag, a file called 'screenlog.0' is created and all output written to it (which is great), but I will be running several Screen sessions and I need to identify the logs with a unique number. Is it possible to change the log file name?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208001/save-screen-program-output-to-a-file/37559327#37559327

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use the following (starting from Screen version 4.06.02 and up):

```
screen -L -Logfile log_filename your_command
```

Comment: Imho this one should be the approved answer, simplest, cleanest and the way the command itself provides this functionality

Comment: I get "Error: Unknown option Logfile" on Ubuntu Server 16

Comment: Same "Unkown option Logfile" on Amazon Linux 2 AMI 2.0.20190115 x86_64 HVM gp2 machines

Comment: This will work only for screen version 4.06.02 and up.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48614247/852862

Comment: The version number can be discovered by [`screen -v`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen). Sample output (on a [Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine) system): `Screen version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17`

Comment: @HaReL: How do you know it is version 4.06.02 and up? That it works for 4.06.02 does not rule out it works for some slightly earlier versions.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I currently don't remember but you might be right... The main thing is that it's version dependent and might not always work. It didn't worked for me (and apparently for others) on older versions.

Comment: On [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), the output of screen -v is also *"Screen version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17"*.

Answer (score 22):

You can edit your `.screenrc` file and add something like this:

> logfile /tmp/myownlog

It is also answered at *[Specifying a log name for screen output without relying on .screenrc](https://serverfault.com/questions/248193/specifying-a-log-name-for-screen-output-without-relying-on-screenrc)*.

Comment: I'm looking for an 'on-the-fly' solution to name the generated log files as the screen sessions are created. Your solution isn't what I'm looking for, sorry!

Comment: BTW, instead of replacing `.screenrc` you can just specify alternate `scrennrc` file name to `screen` with `-c` options.

Comment: This works, but I believe the answer by Nan Wang is the simplest and cleanest.. shouldn't that one be the approved answer?

Comment: On my Mac (Catalina) that does not work at all. I always have to use Ctrl-a-H. Annoying. Seems I need to write my own screen :-/

Answer (score 21):

Alternatively, there's a way to do it interactively.

Enter command mode in Screen via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> and use the `logfile` command with the name of the file you want as argument, for example:

```
logfile whatevernameyoulike.log
```

Then enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> to start recording to the filename you just entered.

Source: [Screen man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

Comment: And then enter `Ctrl`+`a`, `H` to start recording to the filename you just entered.

Comment: This exactly what I was after, perfect for logging when forgotten on startup