# how to see screen node commands logs ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gnu-screen

Im running this command on my ubuntu 20.04

```
screen -S api -dm node api/index.js
```

But the screen session ends after 2 seconds, is there a way to see the logs of the screen session? i need to see why it is failing

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what happened on your screen then just append `-L` to `-dm` which will enable logging of the session.

```
screen -S api -dmL node api/index.js
```

Your log will be stored in the current working directory (from where you intiated this command) as *screenlog.N*, where N is the number of current window.

Moreover, if you want to assign different name to your logfile use-

```
screen -S api -dmL -Logfile log_filename node api/index.js
```

There is also [hardcopy](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Hardcopy.html)  by the way(`ESC h`)

Refrence-

- [George's answer on unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26743/453028)
- [Nan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651839/8495763)